# making a tracking pixel load only once (per each visitor's click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a tracking pixel to be loaded once a user clicks on a certain element (with the `clk` class) in my website.

I barely have any jquery knowledge so I came up with this code:

```
  $(".clk").click(function(){
    $('<img src="/images/track.gif" width="1" height="1">').appendTo("body");
  });
```

First of all, is that good enough? (is there any chance the browser would preload the image? which I don't want of course)

Second, it's enough for me to get this info for the first click only. I don't want to track any additional clicks on that element from the same visitor (not by IP though - I think I want to do it per session, which means if the window was closed? or should the whole browser be closed?).

what should I add to the code in order to make it work that way?

Comment: first, jsfiddle will make it easier for us to answer.
Second, i would do $("<img>").attr("src" , ...).

Comment: how would a jsfiddle help here? the script itself is working, I'm just looking for additional suggestions or comments

Comment: why would that be better? is it not necessary to define the size?

Comment: From my point of view : if you are creating element with jQuery method of creating elements $("< .. >") I suggest you do add all attribute | properties with jQuery as well. That will keep your code maintainable say that you want to change the source of of the IMG to something else, it's pretty much easier (that's just experience talking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser sometimes will scan JS and look for URLS. You could pretty easily change it to be something more like:

```
var loaded = false;
$(".clk").click(function(){
    if(loaded === false) {
        loaded = true;
        $('<img src="/images/track.gif?param=' + Date.now() + '" width="1" height="1" />').appendTo("body");
    }
});
```

This should solve both the browser preloading and the "has it already been clicked" issues. You may be able to remove the query param in the URL, but I'd be very surprised if a browser did any pre-fetching or caxginh of a URL like this.

Comment: how does it solve whether it was clicked? If a user opens the page, clicks, and then clicks again, image won't be loaded? what if he clicks, close the window, and then enters again, would it be loaded? and what if he closes the browser completely and then re-enter?

Comment: Well, you didn't make it clear in your original question that you wanted to have it rememberl the clicking across refreshes, browser closing, etc. I've updated my answer. You could also use cookies, but ew, cookies.

Comment: thanks, can you explain though the difference between the updated code and the former? what does each one do regarding the way it "remembers" the user?

Comment: The first was just a local variable. It basically just toggled a flag in javascript. When you refreshed, the variable would reset back to the original value with any other state being lost. With `localStorage` being used the browser stores the information (on the hard drive of the user) and will remember it forever (or until the user or website that set it deletes it, whichever comes first).

Comment: tested the first one with IE and Chrome, refreshing wouldn't make the browser request that image again. matter of fact in IE, even closing and opening the browser, wouldn't cause a second request when clicked.

Comment: *sigh* your question could be much more clear. I will update again with a solution that will cause the image to be loaded once per refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Jessie A. Morris example is quite ok, but to be really sure browser won't cache tracking image I would personally use some more random string (unix time can be a good start).

Another thing is - do we wan't to track user per session or per browser/pc /... ?

Using some cookie && HTML5 localstorage would then be appropriate (many plugins for JQuery exist)...

Comment: I think I would go with per session, I don't think I want to use cookies for this. so once the page is refreshed, it would be considered a new session I suppose?

Comment: Hehe, @Jessie A. Morris your next solution was just what I commented on :) Maybe adding AJAX (cache disabled) to it would also be a nice touch, JQuery makes it easy for us...

Comment: New session on page refresh - I think it's just the same session prolongued (depending on server-side and if refresh happens before session timeout (PHP has default 20min))

Comment: @rockyraw If all you want is to have it work between refreshes my previous answer would have worked fine. A local variable is all you'd need. AKA, outside the click callback have a variable and change its state once the click happens.

Comment: @nettutvikler Yes, you could do something like ` + Date.now() + ` to be doubly sure.

Comment: @Jessie - hehe, cookies, but ew, cookies :)

Comment: If Opera Mini (small, but existing part) is not of concern (I really wish it wouldn't be but MS thinks differently) I would go for localstorage also, but sadly http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage cookies should still be a "backup" plan. Yes, I know, even in 2014 :)

Comment: @nettutvikler This is why I mentioned the polyfill.